# C# MessageBox doesn't display the whole string of text anymore

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I am trying to display a simple message, which I have done probably thousands of times in the past, and NOW... The full string of text is NOT being displayed in the MessageBox. I'm not doing anything differently, so I don't see the problem. Here's my code:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("The text in this file has changed. Do you want to save changes?",
    "TextEditor - Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Hand, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Yes)
{ //Do stuff 
} else { 
// Do stuff }
```

Now, when the messagebox is displayed, the only text that is visible is this:

The text in this file has changed.

NOTE: The Yes/No buttons are visible, and the messagebox looks normal, it doesn't look broken or anything, so I have no idea why I can't display a simple dam question in there anymore!?... Does anybody know about this? Have you experienced this before?

Thanks

#### OK, THIS IS WIERD... (EDITED)

I have just changed the text for the above messagebox text and now it displays the following:

The text in this file has changed. Do you wa

But the most important part of the question is still not being displayed...

Comment: Sounds very odd. Have you tried it on another machine?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm unable to try it on another machine since the closest person who I can use their computer is about 20km's away. But everything was working yesterday, I don't understand why this is happening. Can you tell me how can it be related to the machine?

Comment: I've tried it now @ Vista - VS2008 but there's not a problem like yours.

Comment: what happens when you delete the "dot" after the "changed" ?

Comment: The asme thing happens. But I also replaced the dot with a comma and now it displays a few more words but still not the whole question

Comment: I have just tried doing this and it works just fine for me. I am using vs 2010 and windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved this problem. I am using Windows XP Home Edition and am also using Stardock's WindowBlinds to pretty-up the 500-year old WindowsXP interface. This has never caused any problems in the past, I have been using WindowBlinds for years, and also doing C# stuff for about a year and a half, and this is the first time that WindowBlinds has caused any problems what so ever.

The reason why only part of the text was showing in the MessageBox still ramins a mystery, BUT as soon as I decided to try and Close WindowBlinds and apply the standard XP theme again... All MessageBox's work properly in C#.

---

**Thank you ALL for your good suggestions they are very much appreciated.** :o)

Jason Pezzimenti

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things to try:
1) If running the debug version, try compiling and running the release version
2) Try creating a whole new project and copying the code to the new project and run it (could be a project setting was changed, then you could diff the files)
3) Try disabling any anti-virus software you have.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, i just finished trying them and so far no luck at all. :(

Comment: How about trying the modal version: MessageBox.Show(mainForm, "The text in this file has changed. Do you want to save changes?",
    "TextEditor - Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Hand, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)

Comment: hi thanks for that  but it comes up with a red squigly line underneith the mainForm part

Comment: I'll just leave here one more possible solution: in my case text wasn't displayed because of occasionally mixed newline types *(both `\n` and `\r\n`)*. Interesting thing that it sometimes worked, sometimes not.

Answer (score 2):

The space between "changed." and "Do" wouldn't be some weird character (say NULL), would it? Try to delete the whole text and then type it again by hand.

---

Hmm... just remembered some weird old bug with McAffee antivirus and .NET whereupon the whole contents of messageboxes would disappear. This was however more than 5 years ago...

Maybe try updating your PC? And - you wouldn't happen to be running McAffee, would you? :)

---

Idea No. 3: Send us your compiled .EXE and the source files?

---

Idea No. 4: Compile it, then rip it open with Reflector and check how it has been compiled. Compilers have bugs too...

Comment: I've tried writing it by hand many times. I've even tried changing the wording, and it still just cuts off the last parts of any sentence.

Comment: ...and no it doesn't say NULL anywhere. This is oober wierd.

Comment: i'm not using mcaffee... i'm using Eset Smart Security

Answer (score 2):

have you tried - just to be sure - to escape the whole string by prefixing it with a @-sign?

like so:

```
if (MessageBox.Show(@"The text in this file has changed. Do you want to save changes?",
    @"TextEditor - Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Hand, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Yes)
{ //Do stuff 
} else { 
// Do stuff }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply - I just tried that, and it still only displays:

The text in this file has changed. Do you wa


...Thats after adding the @ to the beginning of both strings..

Answer (score 2):

Its something odd/stupid - its time to act back by being stupid

First question - are all of your message boxes affected? If not then this case has something wrong with it. If they are all affected then ... well I don't know what to suggest really. More coffee?

Best thing to do is to reduce the problem down to the smallest possible. Create a new message box and only enter your current text (copy and paste it). Dont set any of the other parameters and take it out of the `if` statement

If that works, then the problem is with the parameters
 - slowly add the parameters until it breaks

If it doesnt then the problem is with the text
 - delete the text and retype it - there may be a strange character there - e.g. has the text been near MS Word...
 - if that works, then you are golden
 - otherwise, delete word by word until it starts working

I reckon you'll find out it something really stupid

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions, though I still have the problem. I've even tried re-writing the whole messagebox/if statement from scratch and it has made no difference at all.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to put your text in a variable juste to see if it work?

```
string message = @"The text in this file has changed. Do you want to save changes?";
string title = "TextEditor - Confirmation";

if (MessageBox.Show,(message, title, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Hand, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Yes){ //Do stuff } else { // Do stuff }
```

Comment: Yes sir I have indeed, still has the same problems

Answer (score 1):

I've tried it too and it seems to work fine.
Maybe check the regional/language settings on the machine your running it on?

There's no set size for message boxes in the form.Designer.cs is there?

Comment: Thanks. I've checked and those settings are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating another solution with 1 form and the following code - btw works form me vs2008 winXP en-gb lang

```
using System;

using System.ComponentModel;

using System.Drawing;

using System.Text;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (MessageBox.Show("The text in this file has changed. Do you want to save changes?", "TextEditor - Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Hand, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("yes");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I pasted your code and did not make any changes to it. However, the problem still happens. But the if statement works correctly, if i click yes it pops up a message saying yes, and the same happens for the no button.

Answer (score 1):

Could you possibly try a newline \n after "changed"?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have already tried this with no luck. I've even tried using it with no new line at all and still doesn't work properly